# When a process is busy running in userpsace, can it be interrupted by signal

Tags: linux, signals

What I learn is that the signal handler is called when process is scheduled to run at next time.

So when the process is running dead loop in userspace, send a signal to it, can the handler be called immediately ?

the process run diagram

```
  running at userspace
   |
   v
---A------B             E---------     F      G---------

          ++C++  D  +++++
            ^   
            |
           running in kernel space
```

A: running at userspace
B: switch to kernel via a system call
C: running at kernel
D: wait some events happen, in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state
E: system call done, return to userspace
F: process use all it's time quota, kernel schedule it out
G: process get scheduled again

What I want to learn is which point that signal hander called. can the signal be deliveried at A, or wait until D/E/G.

Comment: The signal handler should get called immediately. You can easily try this.

Comment: Use `kill` to send a signal then look at the exit code

Comment: When the process run out its time slice such as 10ms, the process is scheduled out, and may be scheduled immediately next time, at this point, the signal handler may be called in very fast, so it can't prove your conclusion. @Bodo

Comment: @yuanjianpeng I suggest to [edit] your question and add more background information about what you want to achieve or what problem you want to solve. It's best to create a [mre] to demonstrate this. Signals are implemented in software, so the term "immediately" might need clarification. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241268/330217

Comment: @Bodo, according the link you provided, it's seems that when signal generated at A, then the signal become pending, and get delivery until D/E/G. so the conclution is signal can not interrupt user code ?

Comment: @yuanjianpeng Citing the linked answer: "The signal handler is executed the next time the target process returns from kernel mode to user mode. This occurs either when the process is scheduled to run again **after a hardware interrupt** (and it wasn't already running in kernel mode), **or** when the **process returns from a system call** (on some architectures, these are the same thing)." You can easily try and see that a loop in user mode *will* be interrupted by a signal. See https://onlinegdb.com/ByH8Gx4Mu